# Rendering large images in WebView

Tags: android, image, webview, rendering

I'm a newcomer in development of android apps.  But, I'm undertaking what feels like a large project and I'm looking for information on whether it will work or not, before I get to far in.

As I've read, when trying to display very large images in android, it is most useful to use the "webview".

So, I took that advice, split my image into 1024 smaller images, and laid them out in an html table (not quite finished yet).  Now, I'm noticing as the table gets larger my phone begins to lag upon scrolling.

My question is, is webview trying to render every single picture at once upon loading?  If so, is there a way to make webview only render a set of images at one time?  Let's say I'm at 14,000X x 24,000Y on the image, can I set webview to render the next 5,000px in each direction only, or is this necessary at all?

I can't seem to find the information I'm looking for, but will continue to search.  Otherwise, any and all help is appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

i have exactly same problem and i found use full this library:

https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

you can configure a lot of parameters and using cache..